# How to index numeric value for range facet?

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

My project has products. products has attributes. Attributes can be created dynamically. I need range facet for attributes. But there is no numeric faceting. Below example works only string faceting. How can I get numeric range facet for attributes?

```
//product entity
@Indexed
public class Product{
    // ommited
    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = AttrFieldBridge.class))
    private List<Attribute> attributes;
    // ommited
}

// attribute bridge used in Product
public class AttrFieldBridge implements FieldBridge {

public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
    if (value != null) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Attribute> attrs = (List<Attribute>) value;
        for (Attribute attr : attrs){
            String fieldName = name+"_"+attr.getAttributeId();
            double fieldValue = attr.getVal();

            document.add(new SortedSetDocValuesFacetField(fieldName, Double.toString(fieldValue))); // here I need something like SortedSetDocNumericValuesFacetField
            document.add(new DoubleField(fieldName, fieldValue, Field.Store.NO));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

## Warning

First, know that faceting on bridge-defined fields is not supported on Hibernate Search (yet). If it was, you wouldn't have to add the faceting fields yourself. You may [create a JIRA ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) to ask for such support.

Now, you may try to work it around by indexing faceting fields yourself, and hope the query side will work. If it works, it would be unsupported use of Hibernate Search, though, which means it might break with only a minor update of Hibernate Search.

## Solution

To index your faceting fields properly, you should use `DoubleDocValuesField`:

```
// attribute bridge used in Product
public class AttrFieldBridge implements FieldBridge {

public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
    if (value != null) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Attribute> attrs = (List<Attribute>) value;
        for (Attribute attr : attrs){
            String fieldName = name+"_"+attr.getAttributeId();
            double fieldValue = attr.getVal();

            document.add(new DoubleDocValuesField(fieldName, fieldValue));
            document.add(new DoubleField(fieldName, fieldValue, Field.Store.NO));
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/7630cd1/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/engine/spi/DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java#L678..L689